# Why do I keep getting this error: TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, stock

I have a csv file of stock prices of 50 columns. Initially, the **dtypes** of all columns in the dataset(including empty rows) is **float64**. When I perform this code on the entire data frame[**allst**], it works fine and I get a graph.

```
DATE        S&P 500_CLOSE   S&P 500_VOLUME  AAL_CLOSE   AAL_VOLUME
04-01-2010     NaN               NaN          29.397636        NaN
05-01-2010     NaN               NaN          29.397636        NaN
06-01-2010     NaN               NaN          29.397636        NaN
07-01-2010     NaN               NaN          29.397636        NaN
08-01-2010     NaN               NaN          29.397636        NaN
```

```
allst.plot(figsize = (12,4))
plt.legend(loc = "best")
plt.title("AAL Stock Movement")
plt.show(block = False)
```

[Time Series Stock Prices Movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDdQe.png)

However, when I run this code to plot a single column[**AAL_CLOSE**] from the dataset

```
plt.figure(figsize = (12,4))
plt.plot(allst["AAL_CLOSE"], label = "test")
plt.legend(loc = "best")
plt.title("test")
plt.show()
```

I get this error,

```
TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float
```

[Error Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujRdl.png)

Now, I have literally searched for days at end, to find a solution as Ive got to submit a project and Ive tried to convert the types to **str** as well but I cannot solve this issue/error.

Any solutions?

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please

Comment: A reproducible example of what exactly?

Comment: A small sample of the dataframe that we could use to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Allow me : )
I have made a small dataset above.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more of the context around the error message (e.g. in which line the error happened, etc)?

Comment: @nonDucor Take a look at the link. It is the 2nd line, "plt.plot(allst["AAL_CLOSE"], label = "test")"

Comment: The dataset you provided does not recreate the error - check for yourself. Please provide a sample dataset that can be used to reproduce the error.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you provided the full stack trace.